# Tor is not connecting (how to overcome provider's blocking)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, help, blocked

Long story short - I've download Tor and it worked fine for the first time. Day later is not connecting at all. 
I have tried to run it manually using bridges, but unfo it didnt work either.

p.s. antivirus and firewall is turnoff, time is set online

**Here is the log from using automatic bridges (obfs4) from Tor itself**

```
12.10.2016 14:36:30.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:36:30.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:36:30.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:36:30.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:36:30.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
12.10.2016 14:36:31.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
12.10.2016 14:38:17.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:38:17.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:38:17.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:38:18.000 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
12.10.2016 14:38:32.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:38:32.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:38:32.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:38:32.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:38:40.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 752CF7825B3B9EA6A98C83AC41F7099D67007EA5 at 198.245.60.50:443) 
12.10.2016 14:38:40.000 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:40.000 [WARN] 10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host FE7840FE1E21FE0A0639ED176EDA00A3ECA1E34D at 154.35.22.13:4319) 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host A09D536DD1752D542E1FBB3C9CE4449D51298239 at 83.212.101.3:50000) 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 12 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host 00DC6C4FA49A65BD1472993CF6730D54F11E0DBB at 154.35.22.12:80) 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 13 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 13 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host A832D176ECD5C7C6B58825AE22FC4C90FA249637 at 154.35.22.11:2413) 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 14 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 14 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 15; recommendation warn; host 8FB9F4319E89E5C6223052AA525A192AFBC85D55 at 154.35.22.10:2934) 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 15 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 15 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 16; recommendation warn; host C73ADBAC8ADFDBF0FC0F3F4E8091C0107D093716 at 154.35.22.9:443) 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 16 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 16 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE
```

**here is the log with manually inserted bridges**

```
12.10.2016 14:36:30.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:36:30.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:36:30.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:36:30.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:36:30.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
12.10.2016 14:36:31.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
12.10.2016 14:38:17.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:38:17.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:38:17.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:38:18.000 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
12.10.2016 14:38:32.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:38:32.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:38:32.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:38:32.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:38:40.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 752CF7825B3B9EA6A98C83AC41F7099D67007EA5 at 198.245.60.50:443) 
12.10.2016 14:38:40.000 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:40.000 [WARN] 10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host FE7840FE1E21FE0A0639ED176EDA00A3ECA1E34D at 154.35.22.13:4319) 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host A09D536DD1752D542E1FBB3C9CE4449D51298239 at 83.212.101.3:50000) 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 12 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host 00DC6C4FA49A65BD1472993CF6730D54F11E0DBB at 154.35.22.12:80) 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 13 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 13 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host A832D176ECD5C7C6B58825AE22FC4C90FA249637 at 154.35.22.11:2413) 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 14 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 14 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 15; recommendation warn; host 8FB9F4319E89E5C6223052AA525A192AFBC85D55 at 154.35.22.10:2934) 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 15 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 15 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 16; recommendation warn; host C73ADBAC8ADFDBF0FC0F3F4E8091C0107D093716 at 154.35.22.9:443) 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 16 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:38:43.600 [WARN] 16 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:40:41.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:40:41.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:40:41.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:40:41.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:40:48.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 17; recommendation warn; host 14A6BF7B174B26A6F672A1C0E7D99F0BE3111FBC at 37.218.246.41:55155) 
12.10.2016 14:40:48.400 [WARN] 17 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:40:48.400 [WARN] 17 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:40:51.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:40:51.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:40:51.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:40:51.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 18; recommendation warn; host 1F7B521B5E61D034B72EA965EA12133F9D992568 at 88.198.46.98:42723) 
12.10.2016 14:40:51.600 [WARN] 19 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:40:51.600 [WARN] 18 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:40:51.600 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
12.10.2016 14:40:57.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:40:57.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:40:57.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:40:57.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:41:04.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 19; recommendation warn; host 14A6BF7B174B26A6F672A1C0E7D99F0BE3111FBC at 37.218.246.41:55155) 
12.10.2016 14:41:04.400 [WARN] 20 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:41:04.400 [WARN] 19 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:41:04.400 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
12.10.2016 14:41:05.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:41:05.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12.10.2016 14:41:05.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12.10.2016 14:41:05.500 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 20; recommendation warn; host 1F7B521B5E61D034B72EA965EA12133F9D992568 at 88.198.46.98:42723) 
12.10.2016 14:41:05.500 [WARN] 22 connections have failed: 
12.10.2016 14:41:05.500 [WARN] 20 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12.10.2016 14:41:05.500 [WARN] 2 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, neither of those logs appear to be connecting using obfs4? Please follow the guide at https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en#user

Comment: Yeah, i am doing everything following the guide. Still cant connect. What might be the matter? Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't look like what you're doing is taking effect, it appears to be trying to use obfs4 as a non-obfs4 proxy and your "manually entered" bridges are also the same set of bridges (the default Tor Browser bridges).

Comment: I've tried all bridges. None of them is working. tor just doesnt connect and thats it. I dont know what else can i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `meek` transport - it seems that you're experiencing a SSL/TLS based intrusion tactiks from your ISP, so use that particular transport: it is specifically designed to fight with such type of problem

Comment: I've tried this (meek-amazon and meek-azure) none of them is working. Still cant connect.

Comment: try to use your VPS and set up your own meek server. Some CDN-based meek servers were recently closed as far as I know. If your server will work - then you will need to find more public servers for it

Comment: I am sorry, what VPS stands for? And how do i get public servers for it?

Comment: VPS is a virtual private server - a way of obtaining cheap virtual machine for a rent. You need to check the *concept* of Meek trasport working in your case. If it works - just find a server that uses it or use your own

Comment: You're welcome! feel free to ask further questions - I'm glad to help!

Comment: So, in this way I need to get myself a VPS?

Comment: What about VPN in this case? Is that better?

Comment: VPN connection may help, but it's another thing and it's vulnerable to DPI too. Take any vps on market, it's cheap. Do you need some providers links?